# Insert Dash Barchart into a HTML page via Flask Framework

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to insert a barchart into my website which has been written in Flask. Here is what my app.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title="Mainpage")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is what my barchart looks like (chart.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And here is what my html looks like (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.w3-bar,h1,button {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
.fa-anchor,.fa-coffee {font-size:200px}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-red w3-card w3-left-align w3-large">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 4</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
  <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-large">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Header -->
<header class="w3-container w3-red w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px">
  <h1 class="w3-margin w3-jumbo">START PAGE</h1>
  <p class="w3-xlarge">Template by w3.css</p>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin-top">Get Started</button>
</header>

<!-- First Grid -->
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
  <div class="w3-content">
    <div class="w3-twothird">
      <h1>Bar Chart</h1>

        <h2>Insert bar chart here</h2>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a site where I can embed dash or seaborn or plotly or possibly d3 charts onto one page. With the dash chart, I'm hoping to make a site that looks something like this:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

**EDIT 1 05/04/19. Here is what my file structure looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from flask import Flask, render_template

server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/name')
def name():
    return render_template('index.html')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

layout = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>{%title%}</title>
{%favicon%}
{%metas%}
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
{%css%}
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.w3-bar,h1,button {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
.fa-anchor,.fa-coffee {font-size:200px}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-red w3-card w3-left-align w3-large">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 4</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
  <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-large">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Header -->
<header class="w3-container w3-red w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px">
  <h1 class="w3-margin w3-jumbo">START PAGE</h1>
  <p class="w3-xlarge">Template by w3.css</p>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin-top">Get Started</button>
</header>

<!-- First Grid -->
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
  <div class="w3-content">
    <div class="w3-twothird">
      <h1>Bar Chart</h1>

        <h2>Insert bar chart here</h2>
        {%app_entry%}
  </div>
</div>
  {%config%}
  {%scripts%}
  {%renderer%}
</body>
</html>
"""

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, server=server, index_string=layout)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is in no way the right way to do. But this might help you get thinking in the right direction or just get to think of some ideas? Take it with a grain of salt.

I am not sure what the best/correct way of doing it is but, here are two way I could think of. Either you generate/export a png of your chart and then insert it in your html. OR you could just generate your JavaScript for the graph dynamically and then insert it. So you would write out all the base code for you graph, and then just add the values for the bars.

Comment: Generating an image of a chart written in Dash isn't straight forward unless you use something like selenium, which I want to avoid because it's slow and I don't want to run a web browser in order to generate a chart. I would much rather embed the chart as a web app within a HTML template.